# Remove "date-remote" => "true" on condition, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I'm using the condition remove "date-remote" => "true",  but  it doesn't work.
here my condition is:

```
 %a{:href => current_user.present? ? "#{"/posts"}" : "#{"/users/sign_in"}" , "data-method" => "post", current_user.present? ?  " "data-remote" => true" : " ", "title" => "Vote Down"}
```

but the condition on "data-remote" gives an error. HOw can I resolve it.Please give any suggestion, Thanks!

Comment: `%a{:href => current_user.present? ? "/posts" : "/users/sign_in" , "data-method" => "post", current_user.present? ? "#{"data-remote" => true}" : " ", "title" => "Vote Down"}`  
?

Comment: Its not working @ted, gives an error .syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
...nt? ? "#{"data-remote" => true}" : " ", "title" => "Vote Down")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will work for you

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
  %a{:href => "/posts", "data-method" => "post", "data-remote" => true, "title" => "Vote Down"}
<% else %>
  %a{:href => "/users/sign_in" , "data-method" => "post", "title" => "Vote Down"}
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 " "data-remote" => true"
```

You're using double quotes inside of double quotes, that's really not good.

Replace with

```
 " 'data-remote' => true"
```

P.S. Actually your code seems not very clean for me, why don't you use conditionals above link level and provide helper link_to method instead of this?

Comment: Thanks @joe for your response.. Actually this condition I use for the users who sign in and who are not..when user are not signed in and click on button then it redirect(which doen't need data-remote) to sign in page otherwise it show post on popup(which need data-remote)..Your comment does not resolve my problem. It give error